# Jest tests passed when in promises, but failed in async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs

I'm writing tests on my RESTful API using Jest + supertest.
My `test.js` looked like this at first:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const request = require('supertest')
const app = require('./app')

const genUUID = () => {
  return ([1e7]+1e3+4e3+8e3+1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.randomFillSync(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  )
}

let uuid1 = genUUID()
let uuid2 = genUUID()


describe('Test /uuids', () => {
  it('Get list of uuids', () => {
    request(app).get('/api/uuids/').then(res =>
      expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200)
    )
  })
})

describe('Test /uuids/:uuid', () => {
  it('Get info of a not-existed product', () => {
    request(app).get('/api/uuids/' + uuid1).then(res =>
      expect(res.statusCode).toBe(400)
    )
  })
})
```

It works and all tests are passed.

But I love the style of async/await, so I switched the promises to async/await.

```
... // The previous part remains unchanged
describe('Test /uuids', () => {
  it('Get list of uuids', async() => {
    const res = await request(app).get('/api/uuids/')
    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200)
  })
})

describe('Test /uuids/:uuid', () => {
  it('Get info of a not-existed product', async () => {
    const res = await request(app).get('/api/uuids/' + uuid1)
    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(400)
  })
})
```

This time, errors are raised.

```
console.error api/uuids.js:247
    ERR!error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "Get lists of UUIDs" requires 6
    ....

 ● Test /uuids/:uuid › Get info of a not-existed product

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

Did I write the async/await correctly? Or was there any problems about async/await in Jest?

P.S. `node` version is `v8.11.2`

Comment: I doubt the first one work as you expected it. If the expect would not pass the test it self will stay green as jest has finished the test already.

Comment: Maybe change the first version so it returns the promise and test that they work. Your async/wait solution looks fine btw. So maybe `supertest` does not what you expect.

Comment: In your first version, the `it` callbacks never return promises. Maybe that's why it reports them as passed, without even looking at the results.

Comment: Maybe you need to call `.end()` to send the request as you dont use `expect` from supertest.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle @Bergi You are right. The promises don't work when i add `return`, and it throws the same exception as the async/await one. And it turns out to be the problem of API code, not the issue of jest

Answer (score 0):

The promise version doesn't work actually. As said in comments ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795962/jest-tests-passed-when-in-promises-but-failed-in-async-await#comment88598135_50795962) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795962/jest-tests-passed-when-in-promises-but-failed-in-async-await#comment88598531_50795962)), the test results are skipped, giving the false sense of passing the tests. Adding `return` to the promise results in the same errors as async/await case.

By mocking the app code with

```
const app = new (require('express'))()

app.get('/api/uuids', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).end()
})

app.get('/api/uuids/:uuid', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).end()
})

module.exports = app
```

The async/await one can tell there is sth wrong in `GET /api/uuids/:uuid`, while the promises one still report all tests are passed. So the async/await is correct instead.

And after some debug, it turns out that it's actually the problem of my code on querying database, so a postgres error was thrown in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the timeout limit (by passing a number in miliseconds as second argument to `it` function):

```
describe('Test /uuids', () => {
  it('Get list of uuids', async() => {
    const res = await request(app).get('/api/uuids/')
    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200)
  }, 30000)
})

describe('Test /uuids/:uuid', () => {
  it('Get info of a not-existed product', async () => {
    const res = await request(app).get('/api/uuids/' + uuid1)
    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(400)
  }, 30000)
})
```